# django pass parameter to function in template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to pass a parameter to a function inside of a django template tag?

Defined class and function:

```
class Bar():

    def foo(self, value):
       # do something here
       return True
```

in template:

```
{% if my_bar.foo:my_value %}Yes{% endif %}
```

Currently I'm getting a TemplateSyntaxError "Could not parse the remainder"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to import the template library in your file with template filters:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()
```

Then you need to register you template filter function in that file:

```
@register.filter(name='foo')
```

Then create your filter function like this in that file:

```
@stringfilter
def foo(value):
    value = #do something with value
    return value #return value
```

Then you put the file inside your app in this hierarchy:

```
app/
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        foo_functions.py
    views.py
```

Then to load your foo_functions file in the template you need to run this:

```
{% load foo_functions %}
```

Then you use foo like this:

```
{% if my_value|foo %}Yes{% endif %}
```

You can read more about this at the [Django documentation for creating custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/).